Spark driver is running but executers are not running using spark google operator
We are running spark cluster using spark google operator Kubeflow on Kubernetes OCP . We need to scale spark executors. We have increase 2 spark operator accidently. Then we have deleted these increased 2 spark operators. Now all spark applications are not running only drivers of each applications are running but executors are not sponging.
Please help here
We tried to rollback spark operators but still executors are not running.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
